# FR3DLdapBundle configs errors

Tags: symfony, ldap, fosuserbundle, fr3dldapbundle

I'm using fr3dLdapBundle with fosUserBundle.

```
Symfony - version=v2.0.9
fosUserBundle - version=1.2.0
```

I have done everything as typed in the installation documents. But I catch one error.

```
ErrorException: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ...\vendor\bundles\FR3D\LdapBundle\Ldap\LdapManager.php line 27
```

Can you give me advice on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ldap field for identify a single entry is not the default value setted or is not the first in the config.

At config.yml

```
attributes:
       - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername }
```

Means `uid` will be the Ldap Attribute used for identify a user by his username in the login form.

This entry must match with your Ldap Attribute and must be the first in the list after `attributes`